# Continuous functions and IVT

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f(0) < 0$ and $f(1) > 1$. Show that there is some $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x) = x^{2014}$.

I am guessing that here we should use the Intermediate Value Theorem. It states: Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $k$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) = k$.

But from there I am not sure how to prove that $f(x) = x^{2014}$. Could anyone help me out please? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: define a function g as the difference between f and the 2014th power of x... what value does g have at 0 and 1? Is it also continuous? Therefore...

Comment: So, It should be something like : Let $g(x) = x^{2014} - f(x)$. Then, $g(0) < 0$ and $g(1) < 0$. Is that right?

Comment: @Su003 $g(0) > 0$

Comment: and since g(0)<0 and g(1)>0, g(x) must cross from below zero to above, and, being continuous, take on the value of 0 and some point... at this point f(x)=x^2014

Comment: Ok, yes, So, $g(0) > 0$ and $g(1) < 0$.. But how do I proceed from here?

Comment: @Assaultous2, $g(0)>0$ and $g(1)<0$ right?

Comment: Then, use that $g$ is continuous and the IVT..

Comment: @Aram So since $g(0)>0$ and $g(1)<0$, it measn g is continuous. Could you clarify how I should apply the IVT here please?

Comment: No, $g$ is continuous because its a sum of continuous functions, if you're unsure you should read the IVT statement again..

Comment: So we pick a $p \in (0,1)$ such that $f(p) = k$ but in this case $k=x^{2014}$ Is that right?